# MySQL 8 search in field and JSON extracted field

Tags: mysql

I'd like to search a value in multiple fields and JSON extracted fields.
If my query contain only JSON extracted fields, it works, like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tasks
WHERE
    'Elephant' IN(JSON_EXTRACT(outputFields, '$.action'), JSON_EXTRACT(outputFields, '$.animals'))
```

But, if my query contains columns and JSON extracted fields, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tasks
WHERE
    'Elephant' IN(customerNumber, JSON_EXTRACT(outputFields, '$.action'), JSON_EXTRACT(outputFields, '$.animals'))
```

Here's an example:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/699akmMSPunCXQRsizCcai/1

I don't get an error, but no records returned.

Expected result is getting all records containing 'Elephant'.

How to fix it?

Comment: No, in the second query, there's a column, named 'customerNumber'

Comment: what is the output of `select` of `in` query?

Comment: Provide a sample which reproduces the issue. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: As mentioned in editing, here's an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/699akmMSPunCXQRsizCcai/1